# Can I use option_groups_from_collection_for_select with include_blank on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

I want use on my rails helper a script as follow:

```
select_tag(:article_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select( @article, :categories, :name, :id, :name, :include_blank => "Select one category"))
```

but in my script, nothing happens. How can I use option_groups_from_colletion_for_select with include_blank method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include_blank` is an option for the select helper, so you were almost there:

```
select_tag(:article_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select( @article, :categories, :name, :id, :name), {:include_blank => "Select one category"})
```